# R script working why is graph in shinyio blank

Tags: r, shinyapps

I have finally got my R script working.  Sorry if you saw an earlier post for help, I found a spelling error and then fixed how I call my variables in aes.
However, when I run it as a shinyapp I get the layout that I expect, no error message, but the plot is blank.  Any idea why this is happening ?  Thanks

Here is my code:

```
CountrySets<-c("select","G7","G20","OECD")
    OECDcomparator<-c("per_capita","perc_GDP")
    ##
    CountrySetList<-list(select=select_countries,G7=G7coun,G20=G20coun,OECD=OECD_CDNpercap_tot_ave$Country)
    ##
    # Define UI for app that draws plots ----
    ui <- fluidPage(
      # App title ----
      titlePanel("Canadian Healthcare Spending"),
    # Make the Sidebar layout
    sidebarLayout(
      # Put in the sidebar all the input functions
      sidebarPanel(
        tabsetPanel(id="tabs",
                    tabPanel("Country Comparison",br(), 
                             p("On this tab you can compare the overall canadian spending to different countries"),
                             selectInput('CountrySets','countries of interest',names(CountrySetList),selected="select"),
                             selectInput('OECDcomparator','metric',OECDcomparator,selected="per_capita"),
                             # Add comment
                             p("data was obtained from https://data.oecd.org/healthres/health-spending.htm ")),
                    tabPanel("Provinces",br(),
                             p("On this tab you can compare the overall spending of different provinces"))
                  )
                  ),
      mainPanel(
        conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabs == 'Country Comparison'",
                         plotOutput('plotC')
                        ),
        conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabs == 'Provinces'",
                         #plotOutput('plot2')
                         br()
                        )
              )# end mainPanel
    
    ) # end sidebarLayout
    ) # end fluidPage
    
    # done setting up user interface
    # ========================= SERVER ####
    server <- function(input, output){
      CountrySets<-reactive({
        input$CountrySets})
      #
      OECDcomparator<-reactive({
        input$OECDcomparator})
      ##
      output$plotC <- renderPlot({
        set<-CountrySets()
        Selected_Countries<-CountrySetList[[set]]
        OECDcomparator<-OECDcomparator()
        df<-subset(OECD_CDNpercap_tot_aveplsGDP,OECD_CDNpercap_tot_aveplsGDP$Country%in%Selected_Countries)
        mean<-mean(df[[OECDcomparator]])
        df$Country<-reorder(df$Country,df[[OECDcomparator]])
        #
        plotC<- ggplot(df, aes(x=Country, y=!!sym(OECDcomparator),label=round(!!sym(OECDcomparator))))+ 
          geom_col(stat='identity', aes(fill=Can))  +
          geom_hline(yintercept=mean,linetype="dashed")+
          scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","grey")) + 
          geom_text(color="black",size=4,hjust=1)+
          annotate("text",x=0,y=mean,label =paste(set,"average",round(mean)), 
                   size=5,check_overlap = TRUE,hjust=0,vjust=-1)+
          labs(fill="Country")+
          ggtitle("Canada's per capita spending in comparison \n to select countries ")+
          ylab(paste(OECDcomparator,"spending"))+
          xlab("")+
          coord_flip()+
          guides(fill=FALSE)+
          theme_bw()+
          theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
                axis.title = element_text(size = 12),
                legend.text=element_text(size=12),strip.text = element_text(size = 12),
                legend.title = element_blank(),plot.title=element_text(size=14,face = "bold"))
      })#end of plotC
    } # end of server
    ###
    shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Here is my data:

```
dput(CountrySetList)
list(select = c("IND", "IDN", "CHN", "ZAF", "MEX", "TUR", "BRA", 
"RUS", "KOR", "ITA", "GBR", "JPN", "AUS", "FRA", "CAN", "DEU", 
"USA", "NOR", "NLD", "AUT", "BELG"), G7 = c("CAN", "JPN", "FRA", 
"ITA", "GBR", "USA", "DEU"), G20 = c("MEX", "CHN", "BRA", "IND", 
"IDN", "AUS", "ZAF", "TUR", "SAU", "ARG", "RUS", "KOR", "FRA", 
"JPN", "DEU", "CAN", "ITA", "GBR", "USA", "SGP", "EU", "NGA", 
"NLD", "DNK", "SWE", "AUT", "BEL", "IRL", "ESP", "POL", "HUN", 
"CZE", "SVK", "SVN", "BGR", "LTU", "EST"), OECD = structure(c(36L, 
44L, 41L, 12L, 8L, 40L, 48L, 17L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 22L, 27L, 46L, 
42L, 28L, 20L, 32L, 39L, 34L, 19L, 14L, 15L, 2L, 1L, 37L, 33L, 
23L, 29L, 35L, 24L, 21L, 38L, 13L, 5L, 30L, 45L, 47L, 31L, 18L, 
25L, 10L, 11L, 16L, 26L, 43L, 7L, 49L, 4L), .Label = c("IND", 
"IDN", "CHN", "ZAF", "MEX", "COL", "TUR", "BRA", "CRI", "ROU", 
"RUS", "BGR", "LVA", "HRV", "HUN", "SVK", "CHL", "POL", "GRC", 
"EST", "LTU", "CYP", "ISR", "KOR", "PRT", "SVN", "CZE", "ESP", 
"ITA", "MLT", "NZL", "FIN", "ISL", "GBR", "JPN", "AUS", "IRL", 
"LUX", "FRA", "CAN", "BEL", "DNK", "SWE", "AUT", "NLD", "DEU", 
"NOR", "CHE", "USA"), class = "factor", scores = structure(c(AUS = 6078.94112, 
AUT = 7080.932352, BEL = 6706.35808, BGR = 2213.4896, BRA = 1824.00608, 
CAN = 6681.30592, CHE = 8893.00832, CHL = 2743.006464, CHN = 942.641493333333, 
COL = 1508.04256, CRI = 1922.1024, CYP = 3193.62016, CZE = 4080.563968, 
DEU = 7979.544064, DNK = 6803.6032, ESP = 4324.19552, EST = 3085.181696, 
FIN = 5611.070464, FRA = 6628.256256, GBR = 5668.214272, GRC = 2904.19008, 
HRV = 2353.02176, HUN = 2647.1408, IDN = 419.776426666667, IND = 307.127466666667, 
IRL = 6350.11072, ISL = 5636.817408, ISR = 3484.8016, ITA = 4517.1136, 
JPN = 5746.82912, KOR = 3957.469696, LTU = 3177.325056, LUX = 6556.35264, 
LVA = 2302.95008, MEX = 1446.171136, MLT = 4677.66101333333, 
NLD = 7148.905472, NOR = 8235.11424, NZL = 5070.56448, POL = 2811.121408, 
PRT = 3975.710208, ROU = 1991.72256, RUS = 2077.27328, SVK = 2716.916992, 
SVN = 3984.64896, SWE = 6939.910912, TUR = 1531.34976, USA = 13235.32544, 
ZAF = 1379.19018666667), .Dim = 49L, .Dimnames = list(c("AUS", 
"AUT", "BEL", "BGR", "BRA", "CAN", "CHE", "CHL", "CHN", "COL", 
"CRI", "CYP", "CZE", "DEU", "DNK", "ESP", "EST", "FIN", "FRA", 
"GBR", "GRC", "HRV", "HUN", "IDN", "IND", "IRL", "ISL", "ISR", 
"ITA", "JPN", "KOR", "LTU", "LUX", "LVA", "MEX", "MLT", "NLD", 
"NOR", "NZL", "POL", "PRT", "ROU", "RUS", "SVK", "SVN", "SWE", 
"TUR", "USA", "ZAF")))))

 dput(OECD_CDNpercap_tot_aveplsGDP)
structure(list(Country = structure(1:49, .Label = c("AUS", "AUT", 
"BEL", "BGR", "BRA", "CAN", "CHE", "CHL", "CHN", "COL", "CRI", 
"CYP", "CZE", "DEU", "DNK", "ESP", "EST", "FIN", "FRA", "GBR", 
"GRC", "HRV", "HUN", "IDN", "IND", "IRL", "ISL", "ISR", "ITA", 
"JPN", "KOR", "LTU", "LUX", "LVA", "MEX", "MLT", "NLD", "NOR", 
"NZL", "POL", "PRT", "ROU", "RUS", "SVK", "SVN", "SWE", "TUR", 
"USA", "ZAF"), class = "factor"), per_capita = c(6078.94112, 
7080.932352, 6706.35808, 2213.4896, 1824.00608, 6681.30592, 8893.00832, 
2743.006464, 942.641493333333, 1508.04256, 1922.1024, 3193.62016, 
4080.563968, 7979.544064, 6803.6032, 4324.19552, 3085.181696, 
5611.070464, 6628.256256, 5668.214272, 2904.19008, 2353.02176, 
2647.1408, 419.776426666667, 307.127466666667, 6350.11072, 5636.817408, 
3484.8016, 4517.1136, 5746.82912, 3957.469696, 3177.325056, 6556.35264, 
2302.95008, 1446.171136, 4677.66101333333, 7148.905472, 8235.11424, 
5070.56448, 2811.121408, 3975.710208, 1991.72256, 2077.27328, 
2716.916992, 3984.64896, 6939.910912, 1531.34976, 13235.32544, 
1379.19018666667), Can = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "CAN", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), 
    G7 = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "G7", "No", "No", "No", 
    "No", "No", "No", "No", "G7", "No", "No", "No", "No", "G7", 
    "G7", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "G7", 
    "G7", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
    "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "G7", "No"
    ), G20 = c("G20", "G20", "G20", "G20", "G20", "G20", "No", 
    "No", "G20", "No", "No", "No", "G20", "G20", "G20", "G20", 
    "G20", "No", "G20", "G20", "No", "No", "G20", "G20", "G20", 
    "G20", "No", "No", "G20", "G20", "G20", "G20", "No", "No", 
    "G20", "No", "G20", "No", "No", "G20", "No", "No", "G20", 
    "G20", "G20", "G20", "G20", "G20", "G20"), perc_GDP = c(9.272, 
    10.5974, 10.74525, 7.36675, 9.424, 10.877, 11.30575, 9.089, 
    5.05733333333333, 7.636, 7.2325, 6.7505, 7.7354, 11.6484, 
    10.1648, 9.00775, 6.898, 9.2484, 11.4984, 10.4986, 8.05525, 
    6.855, 6.66175, 2.94066666666667, 3.56866666666667, 7.0444, 
    8.643, 7.364, 8.8926, 10.8985, 7.619, 6.8414, 5.2775, 6.21875, 
    5.6068, 8.912, 10.3634, 10.5592, 9.07125, 6.607, 9.552, 5.36475, 
    5.393, 7.0316, 8.6362, 10.9892, 4.23325, 16.776, 8.154)), row.names = c(NA, 
-49L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Try with removing `plotC<- ` or add a `return(plotC)` to return your plot.

Comment: yes perfect that worked.  thanks.  I"ll answer my own question incase others have the same problem